# If $x^4 = 16$ then $x=2$ : Discrete Math

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Can someone please explain to me, whether: 
if $x^4 = 16$ then $x=2$ 
is true or false and why? I don't get it :(

Comment: Do you know when is $p\to q$ false?

Comment: When p is true and q is false

Comment: Correct. Now this problem is actually ill-posed.The question should have been regarding the statement $\forall x\left(x^4=16\implies x=2\right)$, where the universe is the real numbers or something. **Edit:** More specifically, without quantifying over $x$, the problem makes no sense because the so-called statement isn't an actual statement.

Comment: @GitGud: It is very helpful to point out this; however, it would be also helpful to point out that, in mathematics instead of logic, usually people keep it tacitly understood and simply write (from time to time) $x^{2} = 16 \Rightarrow x=2$. :)

Comment: @MorganRodgers How is it not needed? Statements can't have free variables.

Comment: @GudsonChou It's an unfair generalization to attribute this abuse to mathematicians in general. You should have said analysts to be more precise. And in a discrete mathematics course, as it seems to be the case, such distinctions are extremely important.

Comment: @GitGud: Agreed; and I would say that, when one knows "exactly" what he is doing, this matter can cause no confusion.

Comment: @Lisa When asking a question, it is preferable here to first show what you tried or at least what your stream of thought on your question; otherwise the question may be closed soon. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is false; if $x = -2$ then $x^{4} = 16$, so $x=2$ is not the unique solution.

Comment: But for $x=2$ it is true. So is the answer "it depends on the value of $x$"?

Comment: The statement "$x^{2}=16$ implies $x=2$" means that the only $x=2$ can be such that $x^{2}=16$, which is false.

Comment: I was asked - "is the statement true or false, or it can't be known without knowing the value of x". In this case should I answer also false?

Comment: In the strictest sense, we should report that it cannot be known without "quantifying" the implication. To speak it more plainly, meaningful and only meaningful are these two statements "Every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (say) is such that $x^{2}=16$ implies $x=2$" and "Some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $x^{2}=16$ impies $x=2$"; but, in mathematics (especially in analysis), we view $x^{2}=16 \Rightarrow x=2$ as with the universal quantifier.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely true that if $x = 2$, then $x^4= 16$, but the given statement is only if $x = 2$ is $x^4=16$. This is not true, since for $x=-2$, $x^4= (-2)^4 = 16$. Thus, we may conclude that the statement is false.

Answer (score -1):

There are four numbers $x$ satisfying $x^4=16$ (namely, $\pm 2$ and $\pm 2i$), but only one of them satisfies $x=2$. So the implication is false because there is a counterexample.

Comment: I was asked - "is the statement true or false, or it can't be known without knowing the value of x". In this case should I answer also false?

Comment: @Lisa If $x=2$ then $x^4=16$ is a true statement. But the converse is: If $x^4=16$ then $x=2$ and that is false. It's the same thing as saying: If I drive a Corolla then I drive a Toyota, which is true. But If the given statement is  that I drive a Toyota, does that imply a Corolla?